# How to remove class from the DIV parents from checkboxList() in Yii framework 2

Tags: php, checkbox, yii2, checkboxlist

Below is my code to generate a checkbox list in Yii framework 2.

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
    <?php echo $form->field($model, 'my_property')->checkboxList(['A', 'B', 'C']) ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

This generates the follow HTML checkbox list.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="my_property">My Property</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="Model[my_property]" value="">
    <div id="model-my_property">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Model[my_property][]" value="0"> A
            </label>
       </div>
       <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Model[my_property][]" value="1"> B
            </label>
       </div>
       <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Model[my_property][]" value="2"> C
            </label>
       </div>
   </div>
   <p class="help-block help-block-error"></p>
</div>
```

How can I remove the `class="checkbox"` from the `div` which directly is surrounding the `<label>` tag? I have tried `template`, `checkboxTemplate` and `inputTemplate`, with these I can only touch the outer `div`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are using `yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm` and not default `yii\widgets\ActiveForm` because there is this element styled.

Easiest solution - use the second ActiveForm class so it will be unstyled.

And if you don't want to change ActiveForm class:

```
$form
->field($model, 'my_property')
->checkboxList(
    ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    ['item' => function ($index, $label, $name, $checked, $value) {
        return '<div>'
                . '<label>'
                . '<input type="checkbox" name="' . $name . '" value="' . $value . '"> '
                . $label 
                . '</label>'
                . '</div>';
    }]
);
```